# Character Limit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, validation, limitations

How do I setup a character limit in a specific column to limit the amount of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your list/library settings.  Go to the column section and find the field you want to limit.  Click on the field to go to its settings.  There is an option for ***Maximum number of characters***.  By default this will be 255 for a Single line of Text field.  You can change it to less than that here.

Comment: I go into the specific link then go to "edit column" and there's nowhere it shows to set s character limit. The only settings I see are: Name and type - additional column settings. Do I possibly have to export the whole link and then set it?

Comment: Make sure that it is a `Single line of text` type field.

Comment: That might be the problem because it shows "Multiple Lines of Text" on the "Type" setting.

Comment: What is the character limit you want to implement? If it is under 255, switch to SLoT type and enter number there.

Comment: Around 100 so I think I'm going to switch to Plain Text, save then reopen to change from from multi to single.

Comment: Jim, Jake, Josh McCormick, you now have to click Jordans answer as the Correct answer

Comment: Once I set the character limit is there a way to automatically set a character row limit with automatic billeted list within SharePoint?